FastDDS discovery server debugging
I'm trying to get node discovery to work between a windows host and a docker container run through the VSCode Dev Containers extension. I don't have broadcast support, so I would like to use the FastDDS discovery server as described here. Unfortunately I cannot get it to work, and I'm also kind of struggeling to get good debug output.
EDIT - Below is a dresciption of what I've tried so far.
tl;dr: I have udp traffic between nodes and the server, yet anything on the host doesn't show up in ROS.
EDIT - At the bottom I descibe some progress I've had looking at the backup files of the fastdds server.
tl;dr: It looks like the nodes don't register their vEthernet addess making them unable to communicate in and out of the container. This leads to the question of how to fix this.
I have configured udp port forwarding on port 11811 and set the following environment variables on both the host and in the container:
felix@d26ba4764f40:/home/ws$ export | grep ROS
declare -x ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE="SUBNET"
declare -x ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER="127.0.0.1:11811;"
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="rolling"
declare -x ROS_DOMAIN_ID="42"
declare -x ROS_PYTHON_VERSION="3"
declare -x ROS_VERSION="2"

C:\>set ROS
ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE=SUBNET
ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=127.0.0.1:11811;
ROS_DISTRO=rolling
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=42
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_VERSION=2

I then start a fastdds discovey server in the container as follows:
felix@d26ba4764f40:/home/ws$ fastdds discovery -i 0
### Server is running ###
  Participant Type:   SERVER
  Security:           NO
  Server ID:          0
  Server GUID prefix: 44.53.00.5f.45.50.52.4f.53.49.4d.41
  Server Addresses:   UDPv4:[0.0.0.0]:11811

At this point I have tried various things:

ros2 doctor hello between the two machine
Run the demo_nodes_cpp talker-listener in the container
Run the demo_nodes_cpp talker-listener between the two machines
Use wireshart/tshark with the above
Quit the discovery server

Which has led to the following observations:

ROS node discovery works in the container, but not between host and container (as evident from listeners not receiving messages from talkers, and ros2 doctor hello not showing the other machine).
RTPS messages from the host are correctly forwarded into the container
Nodes are somehow connected to the discovery server on both host and in the container, as the RTPS packets from the nodes change when the server is shut down. As an example, here is the Tshark output with one talker running on the host, and where the server is shutdown half way:

    1 0.000000000   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]
    2 3.005635010   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]
    3 6.010930102   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]
    4 9.013834383   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]
    5 12.016395468   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]
# <--- FastDDS server shutdown happens here
    6 14.177871216   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 172 INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT, Unknown[80]
    7 14.258540831   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 168 INFO_DST, ACKNACK, Unknown[80]
    8 14.411758838   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 168 INFO_DST, ACKNACK, Unknown[80]
    9 14.534955366   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 172 INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT, Unknown[80]
   10 14.642785852   172.17.0.1 → 172.17.0.2   RTPS 744 INFO_TS, DATA(p), Unknown[80]

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?
Alternatively, does anybody know of a way to either make the discovery server output logs for events, or make tshark parse the FastDDS messages to make debugging easier?
Let me know if there's any additional information that might be helpfull, and thank you for your help!
EDIT - I noticed that the fastDDS server has an option to create a backup file, and looking through it's contents I noticed something that might be the cause of my problem:
Nodes from the host register the following metatraffic_locators:
"metatraffic_locators": "{UNICAST:[UDPv4:[192.168.1.79]:17912,UDPv4:[172.24.240.1]:17912,UDPv4:[172.20.128.1]:17912]}"

while nodes from the container register the following:
"metatraffic_locators": "{UNICAST:[UDPv4:[127.0.0.1]:17910]}"

Since the shared interface between the machines has 172.17.0.2/16 as it's subnet, this would make the nodes unable to communicate between host and container. I will start looking into why this interface is omitted.
EDITnr2 - I noticed that the nodes on the host and in the container had overlap in their ports, and reconfigured the baseport used in the container as described here and now the ports no longer overlap. I also noticed that the various metatrafic_locators listed where pingable from both machines, and as such maybe it should work if only I open the necessary ports for the nodes inside the container to be reachable on 127.0.0.1 on the host, so i added udp port forwards on the port range 17910-18710, however, the results are identical to before (appart from the port overlap of course). I can't quite figure out how to proceed.
